# russian character cannot be seen in PostScript File

Tags: babel, font-encodings, russian

How to setup so that the russian character can be found in PostScript file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{russian}{{P}{CH}}-TEST

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange, I compiled both with `latex+dvips` and with `pdflatex` and in both output I see the characters Ч and П

Comment: Why don't you use utf8 input and one of the T2-encodings (T2A, T2B, T2C)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OT2 provides translitteration

Comment: @egreg Yes I know, but it also uses bitmaps fonts and "found" sounded to me as if the problem could be copy&paste so I wanted to know if the choice is deliberate.

Comment: Can you put the PostScript file in some public repository for inspecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard setup, the fonts used in the OT2 encoding are bitmap.

The TeX Live distribution (and I believe also MiKTeX) provide also Type1 fonts for this purpose, which are essentially compatible with Computer Modern.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{OT2}{\rmdefault}{wncyr}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{russian}{{P}{CH}}-TEST

\textit{\foreignlanguage{russian}{{P}{CH}}-TEST}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with the standard (comment out the `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution` line):

[image]

I think your issue is due to the Type3 font included.

If I do `pdffonts` on the PDF I get, the answer with `wncyr` is

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
ECKFFD+WNCYR10                       Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
LABCOG+SFRM1000                      Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
DLOILC+WNCYI10                       Type 1            yes yes no       6  0
EXEAXS+SFTI1000                      Type 1            yes yes no       7  0
```

With the standard setup (bitmap for Cyrillic) it is

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no       4  0
LABCOG+SFRM1000                      Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no       6  0
EXEAXS+SFTI1000                      Type 1            yes yes no       7  0
```

For completeness, here is the output of `pdffonts` after doing `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` with `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution` enabled

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
KMIFDS+SFTI1000                      Type 1C           yes yes no      14  0
YRPJMW+WNCYI10                       Type 1C           yes yes no      12  0
BHBHFB+SFRM1000                      Type 1C           yes yes no      10  0
YHPXLN+WNCYR10                       Type 1C           yes yes no       8  0
```